# Android IO reading file

Tags: android, io

I have this code in `onCreate()` method in starting Activity:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
try {
    parser.parse();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

and I have this `Parser` class:

```
public class Parser{

    public void parse(){
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("texttoparse.txt"));
        String line;


       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // do something on line

        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

After I try run the application, I'm getting this exception: NullPointerException. Also, I've put file "texttoparse.txt" both in projects root, where AndroidManifest.xml is and in folder where both starting activity and Parser class are.

Where am I mistaking? I'm staring Android from emulator, but can I put .txt file just like that into application and use it on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw files (like txts) should be placed in the assets folder of your Android application, and you can open streams trough getResources().getAssets().open("texttoparse.txt").

Since android does have folders for any kind of resources, you usually will not put files into the src folder.